# Check if a cell has a #NUM! value with xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a Excel file with some cells with value `#NUM!` and I want to changed to zero with xlwings. When I ask for the cell value I got `None`, as said [here](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html?highlight=%23NUM!#older-releases):

> Cells that contain a cell error such as `#DIV/0!`, `#N/A`, `#NAME?`, `#NULL!`, `#NUM!`, `#REF!`, and `#VALUE!` return now `None` as the value in Python. Previously they were returned as a constant on Windows (e.g. `-2146826246`) or `k.missing_value` on Mac.

Then, how can I know if a cell has a value error?

Comment: Looking into the source code, it seems like you can find references to how this is dealt with here: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/300fd42285bdc1aab22b168df4ae6c5837f477c6/xlwings/_xlwindows.py#L434. You might be able to figure out a workaround using the info in that code.

Comment: Can't you just change any `None`s to zeros? It looks to me like it would have been better without the fix that was made because without it you could at least determine the underlying cause of the cell error. A better approach might have been to transform the special integer values into the corresponding error indicator string, i.e. `"#NUM!"`, `"#N/A"`, etc — so perhaps you can suggest that to the module's author(s). This approach would also have worked in Mac so the results would not vary depending on platform (another bad idea IMO).

Comment: Currently, this is not implemented, see https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/776